# shm.h header file not found in Linux 3.13.3

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, system-calls, header-files, shared-memory

I am new to for Linux. I have downloaded Linux 3.13.3 and I am trying to make a system call for shared memory. I have created a "hello world" system call and it runs perfectly.

When I compile my shared memory `.c` file, which calls a system call for shared memory created by me, it shows an error saying "shm.h not found".

Please guide me how to resolve this problem. Is there anything I have to download or install any package?

Comment: Did you include `<shm.h>`? You have to include `<sys/shm.h>`

Comment: Please add the code of your program to your question.